# What should I expect the output of my line scanner to look like on an oscilloscope?

Tags: analog, clock, oscilloscope, camera

I'm trying to test my [TSL1401R-LF](http://datasheet.elcodis.com/pdf/58/61/586128/tsl1401r-lf.pdf) line scan camera module by checking the reading on an oscilloscope. I've confirmed that my SI and CLK signal are running normally but the output looks very strange to me. I expected the output to be a set of square waves the represented the pixels being outputted but isntead I just see a really shaky line.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

The purple line at the bottom is the output and even when I free a frame I get different looking lines. I'm not sure if this is normal or if I'm doing something wrong. Can anyone make sense of this?

Comment: First, find a way of triggering the scope at the start of a line scan. Might that be the blue channel? Then things will hopefully start to make more sense.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by that? This is my first project and I've never worked with an oscilloscope before.

Comment: Set the oscilliscope to trigger on your "start scan" signal.  With the trigger source and level set correctly, the "start scan" and clock signals should be stable.  Then you might be able to see something reasonable on the signal trace.  Currently, you are trying to trigger on the purple signal.

Comment: See how the blue trace (SI, channel 2?) has shadowy pulses, at different places on the screen? Find a menu that lets you trigger on that channel, on a positive edge, with a trigger voltage about halfway up those pulses... You'll see a stable clear pulse at a fixed location (traditionally the LH side) on that channel, and the purple channel should make more sense. (There's another problem on SI, the pulses are different widths and heights which looks suspicious but you have to start somewhere)

Comment: You also may want to increase the trigger holdoff to 1 or 2 seconds.  A single-shot may also give a better capture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figure 2 below is copied from the TSL1401R-LF's data sheet. I would begin by configuring the oscillospe's trigger controls so that the oscilloscope captures and displays data only when the oscilloscope observes the serial input (SI) signal is rising and passing through 2.5 Volts (the SI pulse's 50% amplitude point).

[image]

For the discussion that follows, refer to [THIS TEKTRONIX OSCILLOSCOPE POSTER](http://www.testequity.com/documents/pdf/XYZs/OscilloscopeBasicFeaturesPoster.pdf) which I found on TestEquity.com's website.

From the image you provided, I'm assuming you're using a Tektronix MSO4000-series oscilloscope. The MSO4000's front-panel controls are very similar to those on the MSO2000-series oscilloscope shown on the poster.

(n.b. I am assuming the clock (CLK) signal is connected to channel 1 on the oscilloscope, and the serial input (SI) signal is connected to channel 2, and the analog out (AO) signal is connected to channel 3.)

On the oscilloscope, in the **TRIGGER** controls group, press the MENU button. Using the menu buttons located along the bottom of the display, and also the multipurpose knobs 'a' and 'b' (as needed), configure the triggering settings as follows:

- Type: Edge
- Source: 2    <-i.e., observe the SI signal on vertical channel #2
- Coupling: DC
- Slope: Rising edge
- Level: 2.5 V
- Mode: Normal

In the **VERTICAL** controls group, press the yellow '1' button to select input channel 1. You should now see a yellow menu across the bottom of the oscilloscope display (If you don't see the yellow menu, press the yellow '1' button again until you do see the yellow menu.) In the VERTICAL controls group, use channel 1's SCALE knob (a.k.a., the VOLTS PER DIVISION or VOLTS/DIV knob) to set the vertical scale to 5 Volts per division. Repeat this step to configure the vertical scale for channels 2 and 3 to 5 VOLTS/DIV also.

In the **HORIZONTAL** controls group, use the SCALE knob (a.k.a., the TIME PER DIVISION or TIME/DIV knob) to select a horizontal scale of 10 ms per division (for a total of 100 ms across the horizontal display).

The TSL1401R-LF's output signal (AO) (channel 3 on the oscilloscope) is not a digital signal, it's an analog signal. (Figure 1 in the datasheet shows a AO's signal as a cross-hatched pattern; that cross-hatched pattern usually means the signal is analog—i.e., any voltage between 0 and 5 is possible—and not digital.) What you should see on channel 3 of the oscilloscope is a clocked sequence of analog voltages. Each clock cycle represents one pixel in the 128-pixel array, and as described in the datasheet, the voltage amplitude that's output for a given clock cycle (i.e., for a given pixel) is a function of multiple factors including (a) the photodiode's responsivity to the wavelength(s) of light incident upon it (i.e., the photodiode is more responsive to some wavelengths of light, and less responsive to others), and (b) the irradience level of the light that's incident upon the photodiode. I imagine if you sweep your finger above the photodetector array to momentarily cast a shadow on it you will (should) see a change in the analog output voltage AO (channel 3 on the o'scope).

One last comment. Electronic devices like this are EXTREMELY sensitive to damage by electrostatic discharge (ESD). You should always use ESD handling precautions when handling devices like this. At a BARE MINIMUM you should be wearing a [properly grounded ESD wristband](http://desco.descoindustries.com/images/WristStrapConnection_Correct.jpg) with a 1-megohm resistor in series with the wristband (for personal electrical shock mitigation and ESD mitigation) and also working on a grounded and static dissipative work surface (see the figure on page 5 of [this application note](https://www.minicircuits.com/app/AN40-005.pdf) published by MiniCircuits). Most commercial ESD wristbands have the 1-megohm resistor built into them. NEVER EVER connect yourself directly to ground (without the 1-megohm series resistor) as this provides no protection against electric shock/electrocution or ESD.

Answer (score 1):

> I expected the output to be a set of square waves the represented the
>   pixels being outputted but isntead I just see a really shaky line

Pin 3 is called "analogue output". That should be a clue to tell you that the output is not digital. Here are some more clues in red: -

[image]

Comment: This device will output held values for the duration of a pixel output so there should be a "staircase" type stepwise pattern corresponding to the exposure on each of the pixels. So not a digital output but certainly not continuously analog.

Comment: @placeholder, I disagree with the "staircase" output pattern assessment. Each pixel has the same voltage integration time duration 'k' as a function of the applied clock frequency. At least that's how I understand the theory of operation discussions provided in the part's datasheet.

Comment: @JimFischer look at your AO plot from your post ...

Comment: @placeholder, the pixel amplitudes shown on the AO plot in Figure 2 are not representative of "nominal" outputs; they are randomly chosen amplitudes for each pixel's output voltage. (Note that this figure's information focus is the timing diagram, not the individual pixels' voltage values.) Considering this device is used for applications like image scanning, mark and code reading, OCR, edge detection and positioning, etc., this part would be unusable for these applications if the output voltages of all 128 pixels are always equal. (I'm not trying to be a jerk here; I'm just sayin'...)

Comment: @JimFischer You're not being a jerk you just don't understand the devices' operation. The AO signal does not show what you says it shows, the output pixel period t_o (?) over "pixel 1" label shows that the pixel value is held for one pixel period, this is what gives you the staircase effect.  The AO signal shows the output from a uniform light field, thats all. Look at the block diagram, each pixel has a sample and hold, each sample and hold is Muxed onto a horizontal bus (in the poorly labeled "control logic" section).

Comment: FWIW, Parallax's p/n 28317 _Linescan Camera Module_ is based upon the TSL1401 chip. On the bottom of page 2 in the [Parallax 28317 datasheet](https://www.parallax.com/sites/default/files/downloads/28317-TSL1401-DB-Manual.pdf) there's a figure that shows an example "analog intensity curve" at the AO pin when the TSL1401 is aimed at the center line of a bagel(?) image. The analog intensity curve shows 128 separate analog voltages corresponding to the light intensity incident upon the TSL1401's 128 separate light detectors. This figure illustrates the AO output signal that I've been describing.